# Contents of a static library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static-libraries, object-files

I have a static library, say `mystaticlib.a`. I want to see its contents, such as the number of object files inside it.

How can I do this on gcc?

Comment: Is there any way to do it in python?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

On gcc, use `ar -t`.

`-t` option of the [gnu archiver (ar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) writes a table of contents of archive to the standard output. Only the files specified by the file operands shall be included in the written list. If no file operands are specified, all files in archive shall be included in the order of the archive.

[More info here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ar.html).

Comment: Thank you. So, `ar -x libdlib.a` indeed extracted out every `*.o` without mercy. Excellence

Answer (score 73):

You can see the contents (the .o files that went into it) and the defined symbols by using `nm`. If this contains C++ code you should use the `-C` option to demangle the symbol names:

```
nm -C libschnoeck.a | less
```

Answer (score 19):

On a Mac, simply use

```
nm libschnoeck.a | less
```

There is no `-C` option with the Mac version of nm.

Answer (score 2):

It just stumbled over this:

You can open an archive (.a) with 7zip.
Also works for the object files in the archive. 
Listing all sorts of contents like `.text, .bss, .data,` etc. with their `offset, length, type,` ...
Furthermore its possible to unpack all, using a hex editor or notepad++ to view the contents. 
I tested this with an archive created with `GNUToolsARMEmbedded\2018-q4-major\bin\arm-none-eabi-` Toolchain
and `7Zip 16.04 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that you can use `readelf -a` to display the contents of all the object files in a static library.

Invoke the readelf command like this: `$ readelf -a mystaticlib.a`.